# Recurrence relation for a star and a dot wildchar pattern

Tags: regular-expressions, recurrence-relation

`.` Matches any single character, `*` Matches any sequence of characters (including the empty sequence).

dict = ["cat", "cats", "and", "sand", "dog"].

pattern = "* t", -> true (can match cat)

pattern = ".a *" -> true (can match cat, cats, can also match sand, because `*` can also express empty sequence)

Is below recurrence relation captures the solution correctly?

DP[i][j] = True if `i` characters of string matches with `j` characters of pattern

```
DP[len(string)+1][len(pattern)+1] = False
DP[0][0] = True
DP[i][j] = DP[i-1][j]  if pattern[i] == "*"
           DP[i-1][j-1] if pattern[i] == "."
           DP[i-1][j-1] if (string[i] == pattern[j]) == any character
```

Comment: We don't usually check solutions. That's your TA's job.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: Thanks but I am not a student unfortunately. I have done the recursive solution for the same but I am stuck with my iterative solution.